# How to force an iTunes URL to open in Safari on the iPhone?

Tags: url, mobile-safari, itunes

I have the following URL which links to the product page of a Mac app. I'd like to provide this URL inside my iPhone app. However, it always launches the App Store and subsequently can't display the product because it's not an iOS app. How would I tell it to open in Safari? Is this even possible?

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/appname/idxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found an answer, so opted for directing to Appshoper URL instead.